# How to get the height of viewable screen

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have the screen and then when we scroll the screen,the screen size change then how to get the particular height of the screen that we are viewing. I have use the                                          window.innerHeight and screen.height.                                                      screen height=900 and window.innerHeight=725 every time even when we scroll the page.        so what exactly my screen height is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screen.height return real height of your display and window.innerHeight return height value of your browser window without bar and etc. it's a real height of visible part in browser.

So if you want to get screen resolution you should use screen.height and screen.width, for browser use window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth.

Comment: yes. you can check detailed description here [window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) and [screen](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp)

Comment: thanks,,but on scrolling the page i.e.on next page the screen height or screen width does not change why??

Comment: because you don't change screen or window size. Can you describe what actually you need? You want to get scroll position?

Comment: I want that on scrolling the page I should get the area that I am viewing..I think it should be different everytime

Comment: Simple solution for getting current scroll position you can check [here](http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2010/5/9/getting-browsers-scroll-position-javascript/)

Comment: When you scrolling there are no changes in window or scroll resolution because it size stale and it will change only when you change your display resolution or start to resize browser window. If you need to get what element you are see now on scrolling you can use [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) library or get scroll position and compare it with element position.

Comment: then is it correct that the height and width remain same on the scrolling of the page.only when the window get minimize or maximize the screen size change

Comment: In GWT you use Window.getOffsetHeight() and Window.getOffsetWidth().

Answer (score 0):

what you need is

`document.getElementById("body").offsetHeight;`

you will need to add an id to the body tag and make sure it matches.

Comment: I am using simple body.innerHeight in JSNI

Comment: if you use jQuery this would be possible with what i have put together, do you want it in native JS?

Comment: it would be every helpful for me if you can give me the answer in JSNI

Answer (score 0):

```
function width() {
    return (window.innerWidth) ?
        window.innerWidth :
        document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || 0;
}

function height() {
    return (window.innerHeight) ?
        window.innerHeight :
        document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight || 0;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.write("Width: " + width() + " Height: " + height());
});
```